# For $x>0$ find $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^ke^{-x}}{k!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I've been stuck on this question for some time now. I've tried using the partial sums of the series to find an equation $S_n$, which can, in turn, find the $n^{th}$ partial sum and then find the limit of $S_n$ as $k$ approaches infinity. However, I've been unable to find $S_n$. Is there perhaps a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: $e^{-x}$ is a constant here, so it can be taken out of the sum. Can you identify the sum after taking out $e^{-x}$?

Comment: If you don't recognize the series then you can still solve it. Try taking the derivative of the function and show that $f'(x)  = 0$ so that $f(x) \equiv f(0) = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^ke^{-x}}{k!} = e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Note that the Taylor series of $e^x$ centered at $a$ is:
$$e^a + \frac{e^a(x-a)}{1} + \frac{e^{2a}(x-a)^2}{2!} + \ ...$$
But, what is the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ centered at $a = 0$?

Comment: Ah ok. I guess I'll have to read up on Taylor Series to get this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^ke^{-x}}{k!}=e^{-x}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}=1
$$

Comment: But how do you know that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!} = e^x$?

Comment: @BeepBoop see e.g. http://www.songho.ca/math/taylor/taylor_exp.html